# Make image stay the same size after resize of column

Tags: html, image, image-size

I have a table that sorts the values when the user clicks the columnheader. When the table a sorted an arrow image is displayed after the columnname. When the user resize the column the image gets larger. I want the image to stay the same size when the column are resized.

How do I make the image stay the same size when the column are resized?

```
<th title="">
   <div id="p0col0h" style="width:73px;">   
        <a id="0.0.desc">Tabell
           <img src="img/hrm/pal_sort_asc.gif"/>
        </a>
        <div class="resizeColdiv"></div>
   </div>
</th>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wdB7t/). Resize the first column in the demo and then the image gets larger. I want it to stay the same.

Comment: try to set a width on your image <img src="img/hrm/pal_sort_asc.gif" width="73px"/>

Comment: Thanks for your replay! I tried this, but in FireFox the width is changed when I resize the column so the image gets larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#p0col0h a img{
    max-width:33px;
    max-height:33px;
}
```

Of course the max-width and max-height pixels should be the image ones, I just plugged in random ones here!

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wdB7t/1/

Comment: Thank you for your replay! Your demo works greate in both Firefox and IE! My real case works fine in Firefox, but for some reason it dosen´t work in IE. Is there another way to specify that the image shouldn´t change size?

Answer (score 0):

Also add "Height".
 Using max-height will reduce your image if it gets below the "max-". So just use Height and Width

```
img{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay! This dosen´t work because the width and the height change when the column are resized